# Reset the infragistics toolbars location

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics, toolbars

I'd need to reset the Infragistics toolbars location, in order do not have empty spaces between toolbars.
Is there a way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Its ThirdPartyControl, check with Support.Infragistics.com

Comment: on StackOverflow there are a lot of questions concerning Infragistics, sometimes a solution cames quicker that on the support forum

Comment: I can't test it but I will point to a possibile solution found on the Infragistics site. http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbar~Reposition(DockedPosition,Int32).html You tell me if it is useful

Comment: Thanks, Steve, I tried, but unfortunately "Reposition" just change the *docked* position (top, bottom, left, right docked panels), not the toolbar "floatting" position on that panel... I'd like to use something like "LeftAlign"... but it does not seem to exist such as feature...?!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the provided information, the mentioned behavior is possible, if you are using "Save Settings" option of your UltraToolbarManager. To solve your task, you could disable "Save Settings" option. By this way you will use the default functionality of the UltraToolbarManager and your toolbars will be left align

For more details, please take a look at: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/79847/402650.aspx#402650

Comment: Georgi, thanks for your answer. I set SaveSettings to False, but the user is able to move the toolbars, so I need in a moment to "reset" the left alignment...

Answer (score 0):

About your comment:".... there are a lot of questions concerning Infragistics, sometimes a solution cames quicker that on the support forum .....".

Here is your thread in Infragistics forums : http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/79125/399883.aspx  and I think that my colleague already send a solution and sample of your questions.

Let me know if you have any further questions